# Problems importing mixin into another app for apply to Class Based View

Tags: django, import, mixins

I have the file userprofiles/mixins.py in which I've created this mixin

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url = '/login/'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In my file userprofiles/views.py I have the following class based view named ProfileView of this way:

```
from .mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context.update({'userprofile': self.get_userprofile()})

        return context

    def get_userprofile(self):
        return self.request.user.userprofile
```

In this class based view named ProfileView I could inherit from LoginRequiredMixin without any trouble

These mixin LoginRequiredMixin I also applied to the class based view named AlbumListView which is located in other module or app artists/views.py.

The class based view AlbumListView is this:

```
from sfotipy.userprofiles.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
class AlbumListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

    model = Album
    template_name = 'album_list.html'

        def get_queryset(self):
            if self.kwargs.get('artist'):
                queryset = self.model.objects.filter(artist__slug__contains=self.kwargs['artist'])
            else:
                queryset = super(AlbumListView, self).get_queryset()

            return queryset
```

The unique way for my IDE don't mark error when I import the LoginRequiredMixin for I inherit from it is of this way:

```
from sfotipy.userprofiles.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
```

I know that this import way is not correct, because is a absolute import and the right way is doing a relative import.
Other way in where should work is this:

```
from userprofiles.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
```

But, when I want test I get the following error message...

[image]

How to can I do this import and that works?

Thanks for the orientation :D

Comment: Not sure why you think absolute imports is wrong, but have you tried import ..userprofiles.mixins?

Comment: @davko I think that the absolute imports are not suited because if change the module name or if move the app directory to other location, there will be no problem.